# Does the ODE with IVP have a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP
$$x'(t)=f(x(t)) \in(-\infty,\infty)\times \mathbb R$$
$$x(0)=1$$,$$
f(x)=x\sin(1/x)\; \text{when}\; x \ne 0$$
$$f(x)=1\;\text{when}\;x=0$$
Does this IVP have a local solution?

$f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$ and hence this ODE does not have a solution.
I just wanted to know if my reasoning is correct and if my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x=1$ when $t=0$, and you ask for a *local solution*, I don't think there is a problem, since, *locally*, the situation should only depend on what happens close to $x=1$, where $f$ is a very nice function.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it has no solution.
$f(X)=0$ at $x=0$, on the other hand, is [another story](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1441802/266049).